# LinkedLists as Values of HashMap don't contain the right data after modification

Tags: java, list, hashmap

While iterating through a text file of lines of hex addresses, I am trying to save a list of the line numbers where each hex address appears for each address.

I'm using a HashMap of Long, LinkedList to hold the hex addresses, where the LinkedList is the List of line numbers which the Long appears in.

The txt file I'm using as a test is located [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/efgx8p0skskzj53/test.txt), a short excerpt from it is:

```
0041f7a0 R
13f5e2c0 R
05e78900 R
004758a0 R
31348900 W
004a30e0 R
```

I parse each line, and save the hex address as a Long, then populate the map by using my code (supplied below)

```
HashMap<Long,LinkedList<Long>> pMap = new HashMap<Long,LinkedList<Long>>();
//this declaration is a global variable in the program


//these variables are all local
    Long address = new Long(0);
    String newLine;
    String[] tempStr;
    int lineNum = 0;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    while((newLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        tempStr = newLine.split(" ");
        address = Long.parseLong(tempStr[0],16);

        if(!pMap.containsKey(address)) {
            LinkedList<Long> tempList = new LinkedList<Long>();
            tempList.add(lineNum);
            pMap.put(address,tempList);
        }
        else {
            pMap.get(address).add(lineNum);
        }

        lineNum++;
    }
```

I look through the HashMap here:

```
        int evictIndex = -1; //(to tell which ones have been called)
        int farthestIndex = -1; //the value of the farthest away call's index
        long farthestAddress = -1; //the address that contains the farthest away call

        for(int i = 0; i < pTableSize; i++) {
            Long addr = pTable[i][0]; //get the address that I'll be searching for
            LinkedList<Integer> curr = pMap.get(addr);
            for(Integer l : curr) {
               if(l-accessCt > 0 && l > farthestIndex) {
                    farthestIndex = l.intValue();
                    farthestAddress = addr;
               }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pTableSize; i ++){ 
            if(pTable[i][0] == farthestAddress)
                evictIndex = i;
        }
```

After this code, the LinkedLists for each address only contain 1 Long: the first occurrence of the address.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure you are reading `address` correctly? (And are you sure this is an accurate representation of your code, as you are working with `LinkedList<Integer>` in your "loop" but declare your map values as `LinkedList<Long>`.)

Comment: Are you sure this code even compiles? You adding a `List<Integer>` when the value type of the map is `List<Long>`. Show the loop code and            hoe you're reading the values.

Comment: I copied parts over and hand-wrote the others--accidentally wrote Integer instead of Long

Comment: @user1988892 Can you post a fully working example showing how you read and parse the text file and populate the map? The bit you have posted looks fine.

Comment: The code works as intended. The error must lie elsewhere, like pMap being reinitialized (declared inside the loop) or another oversight. Trace the code in the debugger.

Comment: In your last sentence, you say your "list contains only 1 int". Do you mean "only 1 *long*"? If so, please be more careful with your language. Small errors in your question lead to much confusion and unnecessary commenting/wondering. Be precise.

Comment: I think you need to show us the *complete* code from your method (and you can delete the copy-paste of the HashMap code - it's not relevant.

Comment: @user1988892 I guessed at the missing parts and ran a version of your code (http://pastebin.com/kh79aEPF). The loop bit you posted seems to be working fine in that context. I saw 1000000 total lines and 37697 unique addresses, with the most frequent address being `0x2fc7d1b0`, occurring 15858 times. Something else is wrong. Show us where you declare all the variables you use.

Comment: @JasonC I added in my local variables from where I populate pMap. I also inserted the for each loop you had in your code to my program and it works fine. but right after, when I declare curr--its wrong. The variables I use for accessing the map are all declared there also. the undeclared variables after my declaration of curr don't matter since curr only has one element in it after I run that code.

Comment: @user1988892 How do you know that `curr` is wrong? Are you sure that `pTable[i][0]` contains the values you expect it to contain? You may wish to print that out or view it in a debugger; perhaps you aren't looking up the address you think you are looking up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `LinkedList<Integer> tempList = new LinkedList<Integer>();`, but you want it to be a list of `Long`s. How about `LinkedList<Long> tempList = new LinkedList<Long>();`?

EDIT:

Are you sure the scope of `pMap` is correct? If you are re-initializing it everytime you call the method, it will simply be overridden. If you move its scope up one level (instance variable), it should work.

EDIT 2:

If I understand your code correctly (and have implemented it the way you intended it to be), it works fine. I get results like `844754720=[1242, 1275]`

There are a lot of addresses that only have one linenum, so you might be fooled into thinking that you're only getting the first line?

The number of addresses that occur only in one line is : 14314

The number of addresses occuring in more than one line is: 23383

At least in the file you have specified. So you really have a lot of addresses only occuring in one line. Is that the problem?

Comment: @user1988892 see update, and post code on how you populate the map.

Comment: pMap is a global variable in my program, I just added it at the top to show what it's declared as.

Comment: @user1988892 Then please give us more code to work with.

Comment: +1 I'm starting to suspect the case in edit #2 as well.